# JScrollpane doesn't display properly

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager

I have added a scroll pane to the main panel of my frame. But it doesn't display properly, here's what I get that appears on the right:

http://postimage.org/image/extp3ncql/

here is the code:

```
JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(area);
jScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
jScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
jScrollPane.setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
pane.add(jScrollPane, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention that area is a label.

Comment: You didn't have anything after what you got, could you post some sort of link or the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537763/scrollpane-for-jpanel

Comment: using `BorderLayout.EAST`, `WEST`, etc is now discouraged, you should use `BorderLayout.LINE_END` instead

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

1) Use another proper `LayoutManager`, I'd suggesst use `Box` or directly `BoxLayout`

or

2) all areas excluding `BorderLayout.CENTER` acepted `PreferredSize` came from `JComponent`

3) if your `area` is [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) the you can pretty to set [JTextArea(int rows, int columns)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea%28int,%20int%29)